# PC not consistantly working after upgrading CPU

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, quad-core

I have a PC with Asus P5B Deluxe motherboard, E6700 CPU (Core 2 duo) and 8 GB of ram (ddr2 800)

I wanted to upgrade my CPU, and so I went to the motherboard's website:
http://support.asus.com/cpusupport/list.aspx?SLanguage=en-us&m=p5b%20deluxe

I saw it supports most of the core 2 quad processors, yet my bios was not up to date for these CPU's, so I upgraded the BIOS. The process finished successfully and everything kept working well.

Today I went to buy a core 2 quad q9450 from a person (used) that showed me on his PC a couple of times that it works,
When we tried to install it on mine the computer is not working all the time -> out of 8 boots it loaded twice and the other times nothing happened (just fans spinning ...) , when some of the times we heard error beeps. 
Between the times we tried to load we tried to clean dust and replace the RAM with his working sticks and have only 1 stick, nothing made it work.
We also tried a Core 2 quad Q9400 that he had and got the same results.
When installing back my E6700 it worked well - and he showed me on this PC's the both of his Core 2 Quad processors are working well all the time.

Since I seen it working twice on my PC I bought the CPU - I like the challenge :) and now I am looking for ways to understand the problem and fix it.

Does anyone has an idea why this could happen ?

BTW the bios version I upgraded to is "P5B Deluxe BIOS 1238"

Comment: Without those beep codes I am not sure how we can help you.  Furthermore it indicates the CPU was only supported in Beta status.  Additional it only support a specifc revision of that chip.  We need specific step revisions of the CPU you purchased.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it. I'll revert your edit.

Comment: @gronostaj why didn't you wait until he posted the answer before modifying the question back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's [edit](https://superuser.com/revisions/790337/3) to original question:

> So the problem is solved: I removed all the parts and had a massive dust clean with my friend's large "air pressure" machine, also some gentle clean on the CPU area on the motherboard and afterwards it worked like a charm.